# Multi threading with 2 shareable objects java

Tags: java, multithreading, powermock, spying

I have the following situation

I have `method1()` (local method) which call a remote method, which in turn calls a `method2()` (local method) with some arguments. I want to get this input arguments to the method2 in my method1 set some data which will me returned my method 2

```
method1 ()
{
     //remote functon call  
     remoteFunction( input);
    // i want to get the input to method2 and set the method2Output here    
    // so that the set method2Output will be returned mt method2()
    // i want method 2 to wait till method1 gets the method2 input  and sets the   
    // method2Output and then method2 should return the method2Output .
}
remoteFunction(Input input)
{
  // some processing 
  method2(output)


}

public method2Output method2 (Output output)
{
   // processing done my method1

 return method2Output ;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: And what exactly is your question? I neither understand what exactly you try to do; nor where you are "stuck".

Comment: It seems you may misunderstand some concepts, which is making your question hard to answer. Maybe you could help us answer with your ultimate goal?